# Подскажите как сделать вывод комментариев?

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите как сделать вывод комментарии в определенной новости ?
Новости выводятся в цикле а вот как вывести коммент новости ! Можно ли использовать цикл в цикле или как? Буду Благодарен за помощь !

Comment: чем вас смещает цикл в цикле, и как вы себе можете представить это иначе?

Comment: @teran как-минимум сложностью алгоритма? Цикл в цикле это f(x) = x2 (икс квадрат), а два цикла подряд - это 2 раза по f(x) = x. Два цикла подряд выполняются быстрее, чем цикл в цикле. Если есть возможность избежать цикла в цикле - надо избегать

Comment: @Mr.Brightside пятница не ваш день, пора бы и отдохнуть :)

Comment: @teran позвольте [не согласиться](https://apprenticecoder.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/algorithm-basics-avoid-nested-loops-and-divide-and-conquer-often/).

Comment: @Mr.Brightside да пожалуйста, с интересом буду ждать вашего ответа. Вы же поняли, что речь тут о том, что есть N новостей, каждая из которых имеет M(nIdx)  комментариев, и надо вывести всех?

Comment: @Mr.Brightside мы тут не о сортировках/поиске говорим, а о выводе данных за линейное время.

Answer (score 0):

У нас есть массив $news и массив $comments. С помощью foreach перебираем массив с новостями, а в нем через условие if, выбираем для новости комментарии. В схеме примерно так:

```
foreach ($news as $new) {
 echo $new['title'];
  foreach ($comments as $comment) {
   if ($comment['id_new'] == $new['id']) {
    echo $comment['text];   
  }
 }
}
```

Правда это простой вариант, без учета ответа коммент на коммент и т.д.

Comment: если у вас в наличии два массива значит вы не позаботились о нормальной подготовке данных. `foreach($news as $n){ .... foreach($n['comments'] as $c) ..`

Comment: Я и не говорил, что это лучший или единственный вариант. Человек спросил - я ответил, а там его уже дело взять для начала этот вариант и дальше по ходу улучшить код и структуру бд.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы